# Drupal Database Relationships

Tags: database

I would like to know why there are no relationships been built between tables in Drupal Database.

I was just going through the Drupal database structure and wondering why haven't any relationship been created.

any explanation would be appreciated. one of the main thing that i was reminded was that, mysql database engines could be a limitation.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a vast topic among many reasons:

- [MyISAM doesn't support foreigns keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html) and Drupal used this as a default engine until D7 (which now use [InnoDB as default](http://drupal.org/node/301362) if available).
- [Schema](http://drupal.org/developing/api/schema) now support [foreign keys](http://drupal.org/node/224333#foreign-keys-added) so you can benefit from this in documentation.
- Enforcing FK in Drupal would be quite a challenge (Damien Tournoud - one of Drupal most prolific core contributor - [stated](http://drupal.org/node/1014986#comment-3901612): *Drupal is far from being able to use foreign keys properly*).